# Read Digital Numbers in JavaScript (Node.js)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, string, data-structures

I have a text file in which digital characters are there like -

```
   _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  (line 1)
    | _| _||_||_ |_   ||_||_| (line 2)
    ||_  _|  | _||_|  ||_| _| (line 3)
                              (line 4)
      _  _  _  _  _  _     _  (line 5)
  |_||_|| ||_||_   |  |  ||_  (line 6)
    | _||_||_||_|  |  |  | _| (line 7)
                              (line 8)
```

Invoice number format:

Each invoice number is constructed of 9 digits [0..9]
Invoice number is written using _ and | characters.
Invoice number input takes 4 lines.
The first 3 lines contain 27 characters.
The fourth line is blank.

**The output should be -

723956789

490867715**

I read the text file using fs module of node js  like this  and break every digital character in to three parts basically -

```
var fun = function(){
fs.readFile("./input1.txt", 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    var i = 0;
    console.log(data.length);
    while(data[i] != "\n" && i<data.length) {
        if(data[i] != " ") {
            var str = "";
            while(data[i]!= " " && data[i]!= "\n") {
                str = str + data[i];
                i++;
            }
            inputA.push(str);
            } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    i++;
    console.log(i,inputA);

    while(data[i] != "\n" && i<data.length) {
        if(data[i] != " ") {
            var str = "";
            while(data[i]!= " " && data[i]!= "\n") {
                str = str + data[i];
                i++;
            }
            inputB.push(str);
            // console.log(inputA);
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    i++;
    console.log(i,inputB);

    while(data[i] != "\n" && i<data.length) {
        if(data[i] != " ") {
            var str = "";
            while(data[i]!= " " && data[i]!= "\n") {
                str = str + data[i];
                i++;
            }
            console.log(str);
            inputC.push(str);
            // console.log(inputA);
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    } 
    console.log(inputA);
    console.log(inputB);
    console.log(inputC);
})
```

}

But not able to read properly. Can any one help me to read and get the desired output.

Comment: Would it be an option to ask whoever produces the text file to write their numbers like normal people do?

Comment: If that isn't an option, can you at least ask them to be consistent? The 9 is different, for one the last line is `  |` and for the other it is ` _|`.

Comment: Is this a class assignment? Sounds like one to me. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Here are two functions in ES6 which do the job:

```js
function getDigit(pattern) {
    return {
        " _ | ||_|": 0,
        "     |  |": 1,
        " _  _||_ ": 2,
        " _  _| _|": 3,
        "   |_|  |": 4,
        " _ |_  _|": 5,
        " _ |_ |_|": 6,
        " _   |  |": 7,
        " _ |_||_|": 8,
        " _ |_|  |": 9,
        " _ |_| _|": 9, // alternative 9
    }[pattern];
}

function getNumber(lines) {
    // Chop each line into 9 pieces of 3 chars:
    lines = lines.map( line => line.match(/.../g) );
    // Combine the pieces of each digit-pattern together:
    return +lines[0].map ( (piece, i) => piece + lines[1][i] + lines[2][i] )
        // Translate each pattern of 3x3=9 characters to a digit
        .map(getDigit)
        // Join digits together into one number
        .join('');
}

// Sample data
const data = 
       ' _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _ \n'
     + '  | _| _||_||_ |_   ||_||_|\n'
     + '  ||_  _|  | _||_|  ||_| _|\n'
     + '\n'
     + '    _  _  _  _  _  _     _ \n'
     + '|_||_|| ||_||_   |  |  ||_ \n'
     + '  | _||_||_||_|  |  |  | _|';

const lines = data.split('\n');

var a = getNumber(lines.slice(0, 3));
var b = getNumber(lines.slice(4));

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 2):

As Timo stated in the comments, it would be far preferable to ask whomever produced the text file to export their data in a sane format.

If this is not possible, here is one way to translate the numbers into something usable, though I have taken the liberty of changing the format of your first 9 to match the two other nines in your sample input.

If the 9s can be in two different formats, I would simply use a Map to catch both formats.

```js
// Note the first 9 in the first number has been changed.
let input = `
 _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _  _ 
  | _| _||_||_ |_   ||_||_|
  ||_  _| _| _||_|  ||_| _|

    _  _  _  _  _  _     _ 
|_||_|| ||_||_   |  |  ||_ 
  | _||_||_||_|  |  |  | _|
`; 

// Strip empty lines
let lines = input.split('\n').filter(Boolean); 

// Format: line1 + line2 + line3
let translator = [
    ' _ | ||_|', //0
    '     |  |', //1
    ' _  _||_ ', //2
    ' _  _| _|', //3
    '   |_|  |', //4
    ' _ |_  _|', //5
    ' _ |_ |_|', //6
    ' _   |  |', //7
    ' _ |_||_|', //8
    ' _ |_| _|', //9, or ' _ |_|  |' if the other 9 format was correct
]

let nums = [];
// Each "number" is 3 lines long.
for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i += 3)
{
    let num = 0;
    
    // There are 9 numbers per line, 3 characters per number per line
    for (let n = 0; n < 27; n += 3)
    {
        let s = lines[i].substr(n, 3) + lines[i + 1].substr(n, 3) + lines[i + 2].substr(n, 3);
        num = num * 10 + translator.indexOf(s);
    }
    nums.push(num);
}

console.log(nums[0] == 723956789, nums[0]);
console.log(nums[1] == 490867715, nums[1]);
```